# How to Solve Object Eviction Problem in Ray Besides Raising object_store_memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ray

I have a private ray cluster contains 5 nodes in which each node has 24 core CPU and 128 GB RAM. This is my code

```py
num_worker = 120
file_counter = 0
counter = 0
f2 = open('./result/predict-{}.json'.format(file_counter),'w')
results = [None] * num_worker
hundred_reset = 0
for file_name in file_names:
    print(file_name)
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for i in f:
            temp = json.loads(i)
            if temp:
                if all(results):
                    dones = []
                    done_counter = 0
                    if hundred_reset == 100:
                        dones,_ = ray.wait(results)
                        hundred_reset = 0
                    while not dones:
                        dones,_ = ray.wait(results,num_returns=num_worker-done_counter,timeout=0.01)
                        done_counter += 1
                        if done_counter == num_worker:
                            dones,_ = ray.wait(results)
                    done_idxs = [results.index(done) for done in dones]
                    results[done_idxs[0]] = models[done_idxs[0]].account_predict.remote(temp)
                    for done_idx in done_idxs[1:]:
                        results[done_idx] = None
                    done_results = ray.get(dones)
                    for done_result in done_results:
                        counter += f2.write(json.dumps(done_result)+'\n')
                else:
                    not_done_idx = results.index(None)
                    results[not_done_idx] = models[not_done_idx].account_predict.remote(temp)
                hundred_reset += 1
            if counter >= 500*1024*1024:
                f2.close()
                file_counter += 1
                counter = 0
                f2 = open('./result/predict-{}.json'.format(file_counter),'w')
if any(results):
    last_results = ray.get([i for i in results if i])
    for last_result in last_results:
        counter += f2.write(json.dumps(last_result)+'\n')
        if counter >= 500*1024*1024:
            f2.close()
            file_counter += 1
            counter = 0
            f2 = open('./result/predict-{}.json'.format(file_counter),'w')
if counter != 0:
    f2.close()
```

As you can see from my code, I set 120 workers (each worker using one core CPU). My code roughly works like this: every iteration, I search which worker that is idle, if there is, I put my data to that worker, if not, I do `ray.wait(results,num_returns=num_worker-done_counter,timeout=0.01)` which means I'm waiting for any worker that is idle to put my data. After running a couple of time, I noticed that RAM that my workers used is increasing until some point and then randomly this error is shown

```py
ray.exceptions.UnreconstructableError: Object ffffffffffffffffffff0300000000800f470000 is lost (either LRU evicted or deleted by user) and cannot be reconstructed. Try increasing the object store memory available with ray.init(object_store_memory=<bytes>) or setting object store limits with ray.remote(object_store_memory=<bytes>). See also: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory-management.html
```

I already increasing `object_store_memory` until the limit of every node and it never solved the problem. Even when I watch RAM of every node, they are never full when the error is shown. How to solve this error?